# Not getting gender through facebook in android

Tags: java, android, android-facebook

We are facing problem while getting gender through graph api. We are able to get gender few of account but few account not able to get the gender. We have provided the gender request but not able to understand the problem how to give permission to get the gender

Comment: Hello, maybe you should add more details:
What have you yet tried (code) 
What tutorials you are following, if any
Examples
etc

Answer (score 2):

From Now "gender" is removed from response.
See at **[Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0)**

> As a result, the following fields that belonged to public_profile are
>   deprecated:
>
> - gender
> - age_range
> - context
> - cover
> - currency
> - devices
> - link
> - locale
> - timezone
> - updated_time
> - verified

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i know but m not getting gender on production but while getting gender in debug build then it's return